# Accessing variables with different 'last name'

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am using Netbeans to create a Java application. I created some text field its named from `jTextField1` through `jTextField16`.  Now I have to store the values of these text fields in a 2d array, but I am not getting how to do so.  I want to access all the text fields with for loop.

How should I address these variables with for loop?

```
int Count=0;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: why didn't you try creating array of jtextfield instead?

Comment: Please be more specific its hard to understand what you want to do

Comment: The code you show here is placing the Integer value of `jTextField1` in every place in your 2D array.

Comment: Didn't you mean to do: `parseInt(jTextField.getText())`?

Comment: @MarounMaroun sorry, my bad

Comment: There are reasons why what you're trying to do is impossible (or intentionally difficult), it leads to truely horrific code with no type checking etc as the type of variable "start" + "end" can't be determined at compile time so a compiler would just have to assume it works. As others have said; an array is the correct solution to this problem

Comment: `for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {`  From the double loop, it seems like this data should be in a `JTable`.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of

```
JTextField field1 = ...;
JTextField field2 = ...;
...
JTextField field16 = ...;
```

You can use an array:

```
JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[16];
fields[0] = ...;
fields[1] = ...;
...
fields[15] = ...;
```

Then your loop becomes easy to write:

```
a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(fields[i * 4 + j].getText());
```

**EDIT**

In Netbeans, you can use Find & Replace to replace all your variables automatically. For example, assuming the variables are called `jField1`, `jField2` etc., you can do:

- Edit > Replace in Projects
- Containing Text: `jField(\d+)`
- Tick "Regular Expression"
- Replace With: `fields[$1]`
- Scope: Select your file
- Find -> It opens a search window
- Click on "Replace matches"
- You then need to finalise it by decrementing all indices by one (that has to be manual)

Et voila, less than a minute.

Alternatively, if there were only a few variables to change, you could simply place the cursor on a variable name, press <kbd>CTRL+R</kbd> and change the name: it will automatically change all the occurences of that variable in your project.

Comment: I dint downvote. anyway I know this method but is there any thing simpler (I am lazy to change the variable name)

Comment: @Sar009 I can't solve your laziness issue I'm afraid. Note however that with a simple Find&Replace, it should not take more than a minute, i.e. less than it took you to post your question.

Comment: @Sar009 I promise doing it this way will solve you hours of horrific debug looking for phatom errors later

Comment: its netbeans buddy and you have to go to each textfield individually and change it :(

Comment: @Sar009 No, you need to learn how to use your IDE ;-). For example, using a regex.

Comment: @assylias that did the trick sir but cant get rid of netbeans variable declaration present at the end of the file and also still when I right click the text field and select the change variable name option it still shows the old name

Comment: Oh I think I understand: You are using Netbeans to auto-generate your Swing code. That might prevent you from changing the variable names manually - I never use the auto-generate thingy so not sure how to do it in that case....

Answer (score 1):

As other mentioned, you can't do this.

The best thing you can do here is to create an array of `JTextField`s and loop on it:

```
int k = 0;
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<4; j++) {
        a[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(jTextFieldArray[k].getText());
        k++;
    } 
}
```

This will loop on the components inside the array (from  0 to 15) as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that with "ordinary" Java.

You could (for example) create Strings representing the field names, and use reflection to lookup `Field` objects and then retrieve their values.  But that is complicated, fragile and inefficient ... and a bad idea.

A better solution is to not store represent the text fields as individual variables.  Use an array instead, and then you can index them.

Answer (score 0):

finally did it this way

```
int a[][]=new int[4][4];
void convert() {
    JTextField jt[] = new JTextField[]{jTextField1, jTextField2, jTextField3, jTextField4, jTextField5, jTextField6, jTextField7, jTextField8, jTextField9, jTextField10, jTextField11, jTextField12, jTextField13, jTextField14, jTextField15, jTextField16};
    int count=0;
    for (int i=0; i<9; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<9; j++) {
        a[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(jt[count].getText());
        count++;
        }
    }
}
```